# Выборочное подключение JavaScript (в одном файле)

Tags: javascript

Подключаю к сайту JavaScript одним файлом, в нём содержатся функции для инициализации карусели, лайтбокса, яндекс-карты и прочее. Весь код (кроме отдельных функций) лежит в `document.ready` (подключён jQuery).

Естественно, не все части кода используются на всех страницах. Скажем, карусель нужна лишь на главной, а карта -- только в "контактах". Как я понимаю, весь код отрабатывает на всех страницах. Имеет ли смысл вставлять проверки на наличие определённых элементов, скажем, инициализировать карусель только если есть `div` с `id=#fotorama`, или просто подключать разные js к разным страницам? Или же js/jQuery автоматически проводит эти проверки и это никак не влияет на скорость/надёжность работы скриптов?

Comment: что значит: _Подключаю **к сайту** JavaScript одним файлом_?

Comment: По хорошему на странице должны быть подключены только те модули, которые там реально используются. То есть надо подключать разные js к разным страницам. Советую посмотреть на RequireJS для решения данной задачи.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наиболее правильно делать так (ИМХО):
В шаблонах каждой страницы указывать зависимости на только необходимые модули (например, шаблон контактов может требовать скрипт карт), потом - либо сразу в `View` формировать все модули в `<script></script>`, либо ставить ссылку вида: `http://site/js/maps,type=earth;bla-bla-bla` и отдельным обработчиком на запрос браузера собирать и отдавать код из файлов.

Answer (score 0):

Разделять на разные файлы смысла нет, тяжелее будет потом поддерживать.

Как говорит [официальный сайт](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-test-whether-an-element-exists/), jQuery не выдаст ошибку при отсутствии элемента, но всё же проверку лучше проводить. Поскольку эта библиотека ожидает загрузки всех элементов перед запуском своих скриптов, то достаточно проверять вот так: `if (element.length){ ... }` - `element` это блок, который надо проверить на наличие на странице, а уже внутри условия писать скрипт для взаимодействия с блоком.

Чистый Javascript проверяется иначе, например вот так:  `if ( element != null ) { ... }`, сам проверку не проводит и выдаст ошибку, что объект на странице не обнаружен.

Comment: проверка на 0 элементов _уже_ встроена поэтому смысла нет писать ее отдельно